# Reset super-attributes in select drop down for configurable products

Tags: attributes, configuration, json

Currently I have 2 select options: size and color as dropdown menus for my configurable products.  On the frontend, users can select size, then color. Options for color are greyed out accordingly if that color is out of stock for that size.

Is there a way to reset the attributes without refreshing the page? As of right now, I cannot go back up to size and change my size select since some of those are greyed out as well after choosing my color.  Is it possible to select the option "choose an option" and have it reset my choices?  I have been looking at my getJsonConfig() function and not sure where to approach this.

Comment: Sounds like a broken theme, this is not core behaviour